# How do you quickly toggle the background color of an illustrator document?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've been working on some icons that I need to be able to preview in front of a dark and light background and find that I often want to, briefly, switch between dark and light while designing them to see what they look like, but there don't seem to be any obvious keyboard shortcuts to do this with.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing to solve this problem, that might be insane, but still works, is changing the colors of the transparency grid to be the same and then using the keyboard shortcut for transparency grid as my toggle. In practice that means:

1. Set your background to white.
2. Go to `File` -> `Document Setup`
3. Under `Transparency and Overprint Options` set both alternating colors to black:

   [image]
4. Your transparency grid setting will then look like this:

   [image]
5. Click `Ok`.

You will now be able to use the transparency grid shortcut (`Shift + Command + D` / `Shift + Ctrl + D`) to toggle between a black and white background.

Comment: Wouldnt it just be easier to make a colored plane on a separate layer and toggle the layer? Its more flexible abd you can see same icon on multiple backgrounds at the same time if you wish. please note that the transparency grid is not color managed.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new layer below everything with a black rectangle on it.

Simply toggle the visibility of this layer to show a black background.

If you work with the transparency grid, you can toggle that on/off (View menu) to see a white background.